# Unity 4.6.5 project won't run on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ios-simulator

Unity 4.6.5 project won't run on iOS simulator and I'm getting runtime    error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CBAnalytics
Referenced from:         /Users/diverseconnection/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/983BAC55-2713-423B-B5F3-C135ECCC2768/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D4CAC0C7-E3D6-48F5-B264-E6EB715F9709/trouble.app/trouble
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/diverseconnection/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/983BAC55-2713-423B-B5F3-C135ECCC2768/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D4CAC0C7-E3D6-48F5-B264-E6EB715F9709/trouble.app/trouble
(lldb)
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this error is usually rather broad as there can be number of causes. You can try these fixes
Add the correct libraries in the Link Binary With Libraries section of the Build Phases.

If you want to add a library outside of the default search path you can include the path in the Library Search Paths value in the Build Settings and add -l{library_name_without_lib_and_suffix} (eg. for libz.a use -lz) to the Other Linker Flags section of Build Settings.

You copy files into your project but forgot to check the target to add the files to. To resolve:

Open the Build Phases for the correct target, expand Compile Sources and add the missing .m files.

You include a static library that is built for another architecture like i386, the simulator on your host machine. To resolve:

If you have multiple library files from your libraries vendor to include in the project you need to include the one for the simulator (i386) and the one for the device (armv7 for example).

Optionally, you could create a fat static library that contains both architectures.

Also try this

Remove Build Active Architecture Only (build setting parameter key is 'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH') from all of your static libraries' project build settings or overwrite it with 'NO'